# Can I use runTime annotations in java

Tags: java, annotations

I tried to use annotations in method.I can create static annotations for method. But I want to create a runTime annotations for my java method.Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try doing it? Did you read API? Did you do your research?

Comment: @FilipMalczak  ,I read the apis about annotation.I created my own annotations in java ,But My need is while declaring the annotations in java method or class .I want to specify the annotation parameters value during RunTime depending upon on some criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyMethodAnnotation
{
   // your fields here
}
```

Comment: I created my own annotations in java ,But My need is while declaring the annotations in java method or class .I want to specify the annotation parameters value during RunTime depending upon on some criteria.

Comment: @user2815407 I believe annotations should not be (and most probably cannot be) used in such a way. Can you describe what you want to use it for us to suggest an alternative?